# Visual C# 2010 Multiple lisbox choose

Tags: c#, mysql, listbox

I have added 2 value in listbox as 1, it generates from MySQL code and using While loop:

```
string name = myReader["name"].ToString();
string index = myReader["index"].ToString();
listBox1.Items.Add(index + " - " + name);
```

Now I'm making a `SELECT` query with MySQL and I want to generate from listbox, index which I'll use in `WHERE name = ...`, I can use just string name but when ppl have same name, it generates with errors so...

For example I want to generate with index for no mistakes:

```
 string query = "SELECT * FROM list WHERE index='" + listBox1.Text + "'";
```

But when it can't choose only string index which added in top, it not generates any name...

Finally my question is: how to force SQL choose only index from listbox when added 2 value as 1...

Solved with docopen (i already used "new Form2()" but i already added ["Form2"] and worked)

Comment: I can't make any sense of this

Answer (score 0):

I think what you wanna do is add instances of an own class to the `ListBox`. The text displayed for each item, is what `ToString` returns - so return there what you are using as items right now. As fields of this own class you can have arbitrary things - like an ID or something.

Answer (score 0):

add items with text and value data

```
 listBox1.Items.Add(ne ListItem(index + " - " + name, index ));
```

then you can get index value of selected items as below

`listBox1.SelectedValue`

if you want to get index by item index then,

`listBox1.Items[itemIdex].Value`